# Styling the list of options

Tags: css, angular

**Current behavior**
I am not able to apply any style to the list, I need to move it like for example zmenting the index as giving a float: left among others.

I think this is because this information is set to my tag.

**Expected/desired behavior**
In my expectation is that I can define the style I want the list of options.

**Other information**
I'm using materialize along with angular 2, and my input looks like this:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix input-icon">map</i>
      <input ngui-auto-complete
               class="validate"
               type="text"
               materialize="autocomplete"
               id="autocomplete-state"
               placeholder="Informe seu estado"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedState"
               [source]="states"
               list-formatter="name"
               display-property-name="name"
               max-num-list="5"
               tab-to-select="true"
               auto-select-first-item="true"
               no-match-found-text="Nenhum estado com este nome"
        />
</div>
```

This is the view I have when clicking on the input

[image: captura de tela de 2017-09-04 17-27-42]

In the browser the html is mounted this way.

[image]

I'm using this component [ng2-ui](https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ngui-auto-complete > ul li{
    color: yellow;
    background: gray;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/j5CovP?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts